# Mysql 5.5 is not installed in CentOS 5.7

Tags: mysql, centos, mysql5, mysql5.5

I am using CentOS 5.7 with 64 bit. In my machine already have MySQL 5.0.88 version. Now I want to upgrade MySQL to 5.5 version. I followed this [link](http://kwatog.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-mysql-5-0-to-5-5-in-centos/) to start my installation process. When i give "`yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test list mysql mysql-server`" it's ouput like

```
     -> yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test list mysql mysql-server
 Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile 
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in 
 * epel: buaya.klas.or.id  
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in 
 * remi: remirpm.mirror.gymkl.ch
 * remi-test: remirpm.mirror.gymkl.ch 
 * rpmforge: mirror.oscc.org.my 
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in remi             | 2.5 kB     00:00   
   remi-test                                | 2.5 kB     00:00    
  Available Packages mysql.i386                 
    5.0.95-5.el5_9                                                 updates       
    mysql.x86_64                                                  
    5.5.30-1.el5.remi                                       remi   
    mysql- server.x86_64                                           
    5.5.30-1.el5.remi                                       remi
```

When I run `"yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server"` command it returns

```
-> yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.iitm.ac.in
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-test: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * rpmforge: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * updates: ftp.iitm.ac.in
Setting up Install Process
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server-community, trying to install MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql is obsoleted by MySQL-server-community, trying to install MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package mysql-server is obsoleted by MySQL-server-community, trying to install MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 instead
Package MySQL-server-community-5.0.88-0.rhel5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

It seems link 5.0 is the latest. Please help me how to upgrade MySQL 5.0 to 5.5

Comment: Do you have the repo for `remi` configured?

Comment: @Bart De Vos How to check remi is configured or not??

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install it with below command

```
  # yum update
  # yum --enablerepo=remi install mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: Now i am facing "mysql-server conflicts with MySQL-server-community Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community Error" see comment in Vasco.debian answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using following command.

```
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=remi install mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: @vasco.devian the output of the above command is 
mysql-server-5.5.30-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> mysql-server conflicts with MySQL-server-community
Error: mysql conflicts with MySQL-server-community
Error: mysql-server conflicts with MySQL-server-community
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Well give it try with upgrade. yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=remi upgrade mysql mysql-server